# How do I use a variable in a Knex Where clause?

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js

```
    async getSearchRecords(searchVal : string): Promise<any> {
        const query = this.knex(`${this.config.get('database.schema')}.account`)
            .select('name', 'id').where('name','LIKE', `%${searchVal}%`);

        // this.knex.raw('SELECT * FROM account');
        return query;
    }
```

The variable "searchVal" does not seem to work in this, but if I replace it with a static text value it works. Am I using the variable wrong?

Comment: What are `searchVal` and your string literal value exactly? I don't see why it shouldn't work based on the code shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your searchVal variable is empty or somthing. Your query should work just fine:

https://runkit.com/embed/6b1tglm5zi0j

```
const Knex = require('knex');

const knex = Knex({
  client: 'pg',
});

const searchVal = 'fooo';

knex('account').withSchema('schemaPrefix').select('name', 'id').where('name','LIKE', `%${searchVal}%`).toSQL()

// outputs
// sql: "select \"name\", \"id\" from \"schemaPrefix\".\"account\" where \"name\" like ?"
// bindings: ["%fooo%"]
```